# Array into a csv with PHP

Tags: php, csv, for-loop

I have the next foreach:

```
foreach(json_decode($result[$k], "true") as $result) {
    fputcsv($fp, $result);
}
```

and if I put a var_dump of that result it will return a list of arrays like:

```
  ["Id"]=> string(7) "1"
  ["Name"]=> string(29) "Name"
  ["Description"]=> string(19) "Description"
  ["Address"]=> string(27) "Address"
  ["Schedule"]=> array(7) {
    [0]=> array(2) {
        ["startHour"]=> string(5) "00:00"
        ["stopHour"]=> string(5) "23:59"
    }
    [1]=> array(2) {
        ["startHour"]=> string(5) "00:00"
        ["stopHour"]=> string(5) "23:59"
    }
    [2]=> array(2) {
        ["startHour"]=> string(5) "00:00"
        ["stopHour"]=> string(5) "23:59"
    }
    . . .
  }
```

If I put `fputcsv($fp, $result)` in that foreach loop, everything works good until Schedule. The line from csv looks like:

```
1, Name, Description, Address, Array.
```

But, what I want instead of "Array" I want something like

```
00:00-23:59.
```

Like:

```
1, Name, Description, Address, 00:00-23:59, 00:00-23:59, 00:00-23:59
```

(for each day of the week). Can anyone help me with this? Thank you!

Comment: Show us your code, make it easy for us to get started helping you

Comment: Can you show us a useable piece of the JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in your `foreach`, if you have always set up 7 schedule entries

```
$result = array_values($result);
$schedule = $result[4];
unset($result[4]);
$schedule = array_map(function($a){ return implode('-',$a);},$schedule);
$result = array_merge($result,$schedule);
```

Note: You should give the foreach variable another name e.g. `$item`, because you are using a variable named `$result` in `json_decode`

Comment: Thank you! But the problem is, I don't know if in the future the key will remain with the same name or it will be on the same position. I changed the name after I post the question.

Comment: @Andrew When name changes and other things, then you have to change more code all over the place (e.g. the script that is reading the csv again). I just had given you an solution for that exact problem. You can make it better :-)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

```
$result = [
        [
            "Id" => "1",
            "Name" => "Name",
            "Description" => "Description",
            "Address" => "Address",
            "Schedule" =>
                [
                    [
                        "startHour" => "00:00", "stopHour" => "23:59"
                    ],
                    [
                        "startHour" => "00:00", "stopHour" => "23:59"
                    ],
                    [
                        "startHour" => "00:00", "stopHour" => "23:59",
                    ]
                ]
            ,

        ],
        [
            "Id" => "2",
            "Name" => "Name2",
            "Description" => "Description",
            "Address" => "Address",
            "Schedule" =>
                [
                    [
                        "startHour" => "00:00", "stopHour" => "23:59"
                    ],
                    [
                        "startHour" => "00:00", "stopHour" => "23:59"
                    ],
                    [
                        "startHour" => "00:00", "stopHour" => "23:59",
                    ]
                ]
            ,

        ]
    ];
    $header = array('Tr', 'Name', 'Description', 'Address', 'Array.');


    $fp = fopen('test.csv', 'w');
    fputcsv($fp, $header);
    foreach ($result as $item) {
        $row = [];
        $row[] = $item['Id'];
        $row[] = $item['Name'];
        $row[] = $item['Description'];
        $row[] = $item['Address'];
        foreach ($item['Schedule'] as $value) {
            $row[] = $value['startHour'] . '-' . $value['stopHour'];
        }
        fputcsv($fp, $row);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to process the 2 arrays seperately.

I had to fake up some data as an array so I missed out the json conversion part of your code

```
$json = 
[
    ["Id"=>"1", "Name"=>"Name", "Description"=>"Description","Address"=> "Address",
     "Schedule" => [ ["startHour"=> "00:00", "stopHour"=> "23:59"],
                    ["startHour"=> "00:00", "stopHour"=> "23:59"],
                    ["startHour"=> "00:00", "stopHour"=> "23:59"]
                ]
    ],
    ["Id"=>"2", "Name"=>"Fred", "Description"=>"Bloke","Address"=> "1 main st",
     "Schedule" => [ ["startHour"=> "02:00", "stopHour"=> "20:59"],
                    ["startHour"=> "03:00", "stopHour"=> "21:59"],
                    ["startHour"=> "04:00", "stopHour"=> "22:59"]
                ]
    ]   
];

$fp = fopen('tst.csv', 'w');
foreach($json as $result) {
    $t1 = [ $result['Id'], $result['Name'], $result['Description'], $result['Address'] ];
    // process the schedule array now seperately
    $t2 = [];
    foreach($result['Schedule'] as $sch){
        $t2[] = $sch['startHour'] . '-' . $sch['stopHour'];
    }
    fputcsv($fp, array_merge($t1,$t2));
}
fclose($fp);
```

RESULTS

```
1,Name,Description,Address,00:00-23:59,00:00-23:59,00:00-23:59
2,Fred,Bloke,"1 main st",02:00-20:59,03:00-21:59,04:00-22:59
```